# Angular ngRepeat Not Updating After State Change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my issue, I have an angular app which displays users using `$scope.users` and `<tr ng-repeat="user in users" >`.  I use a `sort` service I built to manage how the users are sorted.  The service has two main features, adding to the `$scope.users` for an infinity scroll effect, or narrowing down the `$scope.users` for searching.  Once the data is loaded from the sort service, the `$scope.users` is updated like so.

```
  sort.init('users', planocore.data.count, function(res, first_set) {
    $scope.users = (first_set) ? res.data.users : $scope.users.concat(res.data.users);
  });
```

This works perfectly when you load this state initially.  However, if you start on this state then change to another state, for example our articles state.  Then change back to the users state, the `$scope.users` updates properly, but the `<tr ng-repeat="user in users" >` does not reflect the changes.

Another anomaly is, when performing the double state change the search update to `$scope.users` updates the ng-repeat, just the `$scope.users.concat(res.data.users)` isn't reflected.

Below is my users controller and the ui-routes

Users Controller

```
app.controller("UsersCtrl", ['$scope', 'planocore', 'sort',
function($scope, planocore, helper, sort) {

  $scope.users = planocore.data.users;

  // Setup of sort logic using sortService name 'sort'
  sort.init('users', planocore.data.count, function(res, first_set) {
    $scope.users = (first_set) ? res.data.users : $scope.users.concat(res.data.users);
  });
  $scope.search_by = sort.search_by;

}]);
```

UI-Router

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('articles', {
    url: '/articles',
    controller: 'Articles',
    templateUrl: view_path + 'articles/users.html',
    resolve: {
      planocore: function(Planocore){
        return Planocore.http('/articles');
      }
    }
  })
  .state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    templateUrl: view_path + 'users/index.html',
    resolve: {
      planocore: function(Planocore){
        return Planocore.http('/users/index/id/1/asc/$');
      }
    }
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Sort Service

```
app.service('sort', ['Planocore', function(Planocore) {

  var sort = this;
  var infinity = {set: 1};

  // Initializes the sort module
  this.init = function(model, count, callback) {
    sort.model = model;
    sort.count = count;
    sort.callback = callback;
    reset_sort_params()
    reset_infinity_scroll(sort.callback)
  }

  // Function that is run on submit search
  this.search_by = function(search) {
    reset_sort_params();
    sort.search = (search ? search : "$")
    new_load()
  }

  // Function that is run on changing sort
  this.sort_by = function(type) {
    infinity.set = 1;
    set_order(type)
    new_load()
  }

  // Resetting of sort params
  function reset_sort_params() {
    sort.type = 'id';
    sort.order = 'asc';
    sort.search = '$';
    infinity.set = 1;
  }

  function new_load() {
    get_data(function(res) {
      reset_infinity_scroll(sort.callback)
      sort.callback(res, true)
    })
  }

  // This function sets the order of the sort, (asc, desc, no order, asc, ...)
  function set_order(type) {
    if (sort.type === type) {
      if (sort.order === 'asc') {
        sort.order = 'desc'
      } else if (sort.order === 'desc') {
        sort.type = 'id'
        sort.order = 'asc'
      } else {
        sort.order = 'asc'
      }
    } else {
      sort.type = type
      sort.order = 'asc'
    }
  }

  // Fetches chunk of indexing data from PlanoCore
  function get_data(callback) {
    Planocore.http(
      '/' + sort.model + '/index/' + sort.type +
      '/' + infinity.set  + '/'  + sort.order +
      '/' + sort.search).then(callback);
  }

  // Resets the inifiny scroll
  function reset_infinity_scroll(callback) {
    infinity.results_count = sort.count;
    infinity.no_more_fetch_data = false;
    infinity.ready_for_next_fetch = true;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if (
        ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 400)
        && infinity.ready_for_next_fetch && !infinity.no_more_fetch_data
        && (infinity.results_count >= $('[data-user-id]').length)
      ) {
        // $('.spinner-footer').show();
        fetch_set(callback);
      }
    })
  }

  // Fetches next chuck of data from PlanoCore
  function fetch_set(callback) {
    console.log('fetch');
    infinity.set += 1;
    infinity.ready_for_next_fetch = false
    get_data(function(res) {
      callback(res);
      infinity.ready_for_next_fetch = true;
    })
  }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">

    <div class="pull-left">
      <h1>Users</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Search -->
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="btn btn-success margin-top-20 pull-right" data-target=".new_user_tab" data-toggle="tab">New +</a>
      <form class="default margin-top-20 pull-right margin-right-10" role="search" ng-submit="search_by(searchText)">
        <div class="input-group width-260">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i type="text" class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Users" ng-model="searchText" autofocus>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- New/Edit Form -->
  <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="fixed">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane new_user_tab active">
          <div ng-include="'/assets/views/users/new.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane edit_user_tab">
          <div ng-include="'/assets/views/users/edit.html'"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- User Index -->
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">

    <!-- New/Edit Small Form -->
    <div class="tab-content visible-sm visible-xs">
      <div class="tab-pane new_user_tab active">
        <div ng-include="'/assets/views/users/new_sm.html'"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane edit_user_tab">
        <div ng-include="'/assets/views/users/edit_sm.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="width-40">ID</th>
          <th class="width-180">Name <i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="sort_by('first_name')"></i></th>
          <th>Email  <i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="sort_by('email')"></i></th>
          <th class="width-40"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users" data-user-id={{user.id}}>
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
          <td><a ng-click="edit(user)" data-target=".edit_user_tab" data-toggle="tab">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</a></td>
          <td>{{user.email}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <b class="text-danger" ng-click="confirm_remove_user(user)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userRemoveModal">X</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="pagination-bottom" class="center"></div>
    <br><br><br>
    <br><br><br>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Infinity Scroll working with users state initially.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ZGM.png)

[Infinity Scroll NOT work with double state change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPFco.png)

Comment: For every new dom element ng-repeat creates, it creates a new child scope. Could this possibly be your problem? Hard to tell without seeing the markup

Comment: I would be happy to add anything, by markup do you mean the users state HTML?

Comment: the html including the dom element that declares UsersCtrl and the ng-repeat that is not updating

Comment: The UsersCtrl declaration is made in the ui-router, and I will post the html.

Comment: In your `sort.init()` function, did you try to do a `$scope.apply()` after you set `$scope.user` ?

Comment: Along my previous comment, scope functions confirm_remove_user and edit will not change $scope. users